# How do I call the methods of three separate classes?

Tags: c#, class, object, methods

I have a class called **'Degree'**

It has a **method** named '**getDegree()**' that prints *"I got a degree"*

The **'Degree'** class also has two sub-classes named **'Undergraduate'** and **'Postgraduate'**

Each have a **‘getDegree()’** method that prints *"I am an Undergraduate"* and *"I am a Postgraduate"* respectively.

I want to know how to call the **'getDegree()'** method by creating separate objects for each three classes.

Here's my code...

```
class Program
{
    class Degree
    {
        static void getDegree()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I got a degree");               
        }

        class Undergraduate
        {
            static void getDegree()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I am an Undergraduate");
            }

        }

        class Postgraduate
        {
            static void getDegree()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I am a Postgraduate");
            }

        }
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Degree.x;
    Undergraduate.y;
    Postgraduate.z;

    x.getDegree();
    y.getDegree();
    z.getDegree();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Maybe you just need to change methods from `static` to `public`, then use `new` to create instances and call methods.

Comment: You day you have two "sub-classes". You don't. You have two "nested classes". If you want subclasses then you want to inherit them, not nest them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read up a bit on Object-Oriented Programming Concepts.

What you are referring as subclass is not really a subclass, but a nested class. To make the `Undergraduate` and `Postgraduate` classes subclass of the `Degree`, you want to do something like this:

```
class Degree {}
class Undergraduate : Degree {}
class Postgraduate : Degree {}
```

That's the first part.

So now you want to treat Undergraduate and Postgraduate as Degrees. You will define the getDegree method as virtual. (By the way, I suggest you follow the C# Style Guide [[msdn]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/), [[github]](https://github.com/raywenderlich/c-sharp-style-guide) and write it in PascalCase -> GetDegree).

Then, in your classes you can `override` the method and provide your own implementation for each subclass. So your classes can look like this:

```
public class Degree 
{
    public virtual string GetDegree()
    {
        return "I am a degree";
    }
}

public class Undergraduate : Degree 
{
    public override string GetDegree()
    {
        return "I am an undergrad";
    }
}

public class Postgraduate : Degree 
{
    public override string GetDegree()
    {
        return "I am a postgrad";
    }
}
```

Finally you can declare the objects and all be of the same type (Degree):

```
Degree d1 = new Degree();
Degree d2 = new Undergraduate();
Degree d3 = new Postgraduate();

d1.GetDegree();
d2.GetDegree();
d3.GetDegree();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is just wrong. Should be:

```
Degree x = new Degree();
Degree.Undergraduate y = new Degree.Undergraduate();
Degree.Postgraduate z = new Degree.Postgraduate();

x.getDegree();
y.getDegree();
z.getDegree();
```

Note that you've nested `Undergraduate` and `Postgraduate` inside `Degree`, which is slightly unusual.

Note also that `Main` should be inside `Program`

Also as in the comment above, `static` should be removed.

Plus, the methods need to be declared as `public`.

In full:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    class Degree
    {
        public void getDegree()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I got a degree");
        }

        public class Undergraduate
        {
            public void getDegree()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I am an Undergraduate");
            }

        }

        public class Postgraduate
        {
            public void getDegree()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I am a Postgraduate");
            }

        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Degree x = new Degree();
        Degree.Undergraduate y = new Degree.Undergraduate();
        Degree.Postgraduate z = new Degree.Postgraduate();

        x.getDegree();
        y.getDegree();
        z.getDegree();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please address the question that the OP has asked - and show your version of his classes at the same time.

Comment: @Enigmativity 'I want to know how to call the 'getDegree()' method by creating separate objects for each three classes.' How am I not answering the question?

Comment: I'd suggest you explain what the OP has done wrong with his existing code and explain the various ways to fix it. You've given one of the two immediate ones I can think of. And you've missed what the OP is actually probably trying to do - that is use inheritance.

Comment: So you're not saying I should 'address the question that the OP has asked', rather I should deal with 'what the OP is actually probably trying to do'?

Comment: No, sorry. I've branched in to two things. First answer the question that the OP has asked. Your answer doesn't explain what the OP is doing wrong and how he should modify his code. You're just launching in to a solution without explaining how you got there. Then, secondly, you should probably read between the lines and explain how the solution would look with inheritance.

Comment: I'm not criticising, just trying to help you to get a good answer for the OP.

Comment: Nesting is not really anything at all in C#. It's a way of organizing where you put things, but not really changing what they do. Normally we put classes in a namespace which groups together classes related to the same are of work. If a number of classes are *really* closely related you can store them inside another class by nesting. But there's no automatic relationship between them - it's just where the code is written.

Comment: This is probably my mistake over here. I thought creating sub-classes and nesting were basically the same thing. That's why I ended up nesting them. Jasper, @Enigmativity, I really appreciate your guidance over here. Both of your answers helped me realize my mistakes clearly. Now I know how to create sub-classes and to call methods through objects, either if it's a sub-class or a nested one! Thanks guys! :)

Comment: @JasperKent - Nesting of classes in c# allows for some interesting edge cases. You can define a private nested class with public properties that are not accessible outside of the outer class, but are allowed to be updated within the outer class. This is a great way to implement interfaces or abstract classes in a way that further locks down the accessibility of a class. It's a good feature.

Comment: @Enigmativity yeah, my bad expression. Certainly nested classes affect encapsulation. I was trying to point out that they don't make a structural difference, unlike, say, nesting in Java.

Answer (score 0):

There's some confusion over the inheritance here.

A simple test for correctness of inheritance is the 'is a kind of' relationship. If we can reasonably say 'A cat is a kind of mammal' then we probably have okay inheritance (though there are far more thorough tests).

So can we say 'An Undergraduate is a kind of Degree.'?

Tricky. It depends what we mean by Undergraduate. Is it the individual or a type of degree? Not clear from the class name, but the `getDegree()` suggests it's the individual: 'I am an Undergraduate'.

To summarize I'd say:

'An Undergraduate is a kind of Student'

'A B.Sc. is a kind of Degree'

Seems fussy, but these things turn round to bite you in the long run if you get them wrong.

Comment: I like where you're going with this. Why create a new answer when you could put this in the one answer? It seems like you're making a very good argument.

Comment: Yeah, I always wonder about multiple answers, but they are address in completely different issues. One is simply syntax, this one is OOD. There's not really any interrelation between the two.

Comment: I'd go with one answer and tell a story. Take the OP from where they are to where they should be.